# Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length in ASP.NET AJAX - How to Resolve?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, ajax, aspxgridview

I'm facing a tough problem with my ASP.NET web app that uses AJAX. When I press the submit button on my webpage, I'm getting an error that says "Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length." Oddly, even though this error occurs, the data I need is showing up correctly on the page. The trouble is, the page keeps loading forever, and the "please wait" message never disappears. It's also showing an error in the browser's console.

My form table

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="projectbyorganization.aspx.cs" Inherits="projectbysolution" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>
<%@ Register Src="ActionItemsUC.ascx" TagName="ActionItemsUC" TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="ajax" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="DetailContentPlaceHolder" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"
    ID="cntProjectByStatus">

    <ajax:ScriptManagerProxy ID="stmngrProjectByStatus" runat="server">
    </ajax:ScriptManagerProxy>
    <asp:Timer runat="server" Enabled="false" Interval="60000" ID="tickerTimer" />
            <table id="tblHighLevelPageTable" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table style="float: left; width: 55%">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="panFilterOptionsHeader" runat="server" CssClass="panelHeader" Height="22px">
                                                <table width="100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Literal ID="litFilterOptions" runat="server" Text="Filter Options"></asp:Literal>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="panFilterOptions" runat="server" CssClass="collapsePanel">
                                                <table style="width: 100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr class="oddrow">
                                                            <td>
                                                                <asp:Panel ID="panSettings" runat="server" CssClass="roundedPanel" Width="100%">
                                                                    <table width="100%">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblprojectLead" runat="server" CssClass="Label" Text="Project Lead:"></asp:Label>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjectLead" runat="server" CssClass="combobox" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                                                                        CausesValidation="false" EnableViewState="true" Width="350px">
                                                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="0" Selected="True" />
                                                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                                 </td>
                                                                              </tr>
                                                                              <tr>
                                                                              <td>
                                                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblProjectLocation" runat="server" CssClass="Label" Text="Project Location:"></asp:Label>
                                                                               </td>
                                                                               <td>
                                                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjectLocation" runat="server" CssClass="combobox" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                                                                        CausesValidation="false" EnableViewState="true">
                                                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="0" Selected="true" />
                                                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                                 </td>
                                                                                 </tr>
                                                                                 <tr>
                                                                                 <td>
                                                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="Label" Text="Service Area:"></asp:Label>
                                                                                    <br />
                                                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="(Press control to select more than one value.)"></asp:Label>
                                                                                 </td>
                                                                                 <td>
                                                                                    <asp:ListBox ID="lstBoxServiceArea" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" DataSourceID="odsServiceArea" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" AppendDataBoundItems="True" OnDataBound="lstBoxServiceArea_DataBound">
                                                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">All</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                    </asp:ListBox>
                                                                                 </td>
                                                                                 </tr>
                                                                                 <tr>
                                                                                 <td>
                                                                                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsServiceArea" runat="server" SelectMethod="SelectAllServiceArea"
                                                                                        TypeName="DataService.Capability" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
                                                                                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                                                                  </td>
                                                                                  <td dir="ltr">
                                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="  Submit  " CssClass="button" CausesValidation="false">
                                                                                    </asp:Button>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </asp:Panel>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <table style="float: right; width: 40%">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="panViewOptionsHeader" runat="server" CssClass="panelHeader" Height="22px">
                                                <table width="100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Literal ID="litViewOptions" runat="server" Text="View Options"></asp:Literal>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="panViewOptions" runat="server" CssClass="collapsePanel">
                                                <table style="width: 100%" class="tablehead" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr class="oddrow">
                                                            <td>
                                                                <asp:Panel ID="panViews" runat="server" CssClass="roundedPanel" Width="100%">
                                                                    <table id="tblViews" cellpadding="4" width="95%" runat="server">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left" nowrap="nowrap">
                                                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblHighlight" runat="server" CssClass="Label" Text="Enable Highlight:"></asp:Label>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHighlightEnable" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" CausesValidation="False"
                                                                                        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:CheckBox>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; white-space: nowrap">
                                                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRefresh" runat="server" CssClass="Label" Text="Auto Refresh:"></asp:Label>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRefresh" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" CausesValidation="False"
                                                                                        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkRefresh_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td>
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> 
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td nowrap="nowrap" style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left">
                                                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSettings" OnClick="lbtnSettings_Click" runat="server" CausesValidation="False">Reset Settings</asp:LinkButton>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </asp:Panel>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style="width: 100%">
                                <a onclick="collapseAll(InnerPanels);collapseAll(MainPanels);" href="#" target="_self">
                                    [Collapse All]</a> | <a onclick="ExpandAll(MainPanels);ExpandAll(InnerPanels);" href="#"
                                        target="_self">[Expand All]</a> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                   </tbody>
             </table>
            <ajax:UpdatePanel ID="upanProjectByOrganization" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"
            RenderMode="Block">
            <Triggers>
                <ajax:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
                <ajax:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tickerTimer" EventName="Tick" />
                <ajax:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkRefresh" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                <ajax:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkHighlightEnable" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
             <table id="tblUpdate" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3">
                                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhAutogeneratedControls" runat="server"> </asp:PlaceHolder>
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litArrays" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litInnerArrays" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                           
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3">
                                            <asp:Panel ID="panCapabilitiesHeader" runat="server" CssClass="collapsePanelHeader"
                                                Height="30px" Width="100%">
                                                <table width="100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Literal ID="litOrganizations" runat="server" Text="Organizations" />
                                                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="text-align: right">
                                                            <asp:Image ID="imgCapabilities" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/expand_blue.jpg" /></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="panOrganizationsDetails" runat="server" CssClass="collapsePanel" Height="100%"
                                                Width="100%">
                                                <br />
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                            <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpanOrganizations" runat="Server" TargetControlID="panOrganizationsDetails"
                                                ExpandControlID="panCapabilitiesHeader" CollapseControlID="panCapabilitiesHeader"
                                                ExpandedText="(Hide Details...)" CollapsedText="(Show Details...)" ImageControlID="imgCapabilities"
                                                ExpandedImage="~/images/collapse_blue.jpg" CollapsedImage="~/images/expand_blue.jpg"
                                                SuppressPostBack="true" AutoExpand="false" AutoCollapse="false" BehaviorID="cpanCapabilities"
                                                Collapsed="true">
                                            </ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
                                            
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3">
                                            &nbsp;<br />
                                            <a href="Projects/closedprojects.aspx">Closed Projects</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </ajax:UpdatePanel>

    <script type="text/xml-script">
        <page xmlns:script="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xml-script/2005">
            <references>
            </references>
            <components>
                <profile id="profilecontrol" autoSave="false"/>

                 <select id="<%=ddlProjectLead.ClientID%>" >
                        <bindings>
                            <binding dataContext="profilecontrol" dataPath="ProjectLead" property="selectedValue" direction="InOut" />
                        </bindings>
                 </select>
              
                 <select id="<%=ddlProjectLocation.ClientID %>" >
                        <bindings>
                            <binding dataContext="profilecontrol" dataPath="ProjectLocation" property="selectedValue" direction="InOut" />
                        </bindings>
                 </select>
               
                 <checkBox id="<%=chkRefresh.ClientID %>">
                        <bindings>
                            <binding dataContext="profilecontrol" dataPath="AutoRefresh" property="checked" direction="InOut" />
                        </bindings>
                 </checkBox>
                 
                 <checkBox id = "<%=chkHighlightEnable.ClientID %>">
                     <bindings>
                         <binding dataContext="profilecontrol" dataPath="Highlight" property="checked" direction="InOut" />
                     </bindings>
                 </checkBox>
                
            </components>
        </page>
    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

in my aspx.cs

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

When I click the 'Submit' button in my application, it triggers an AJAX call, and I'm encountering an error on the client side. I've verified that it's not a server-side error while debugging. The peculiar thing is that I'm not explicitly using any JavaScript code in my application. Is there a method to handle these client-side errors effectively?

```
<ajax:UpdatePanel ID="upanProject" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"
            RenderMode="Block">
            <Triggers>
                <ajax:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
                <ajax:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tickerTimer" EventName="Tick" />
                <ajax:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkRefresh" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                <ajax:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkHighlightEnable" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
            </Triggers>
```

Here are the screenshot of the error:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to debug online and when i first open the page i can see Array value is =134
[image]

But when i click on button submit it shows Array value = 135
[image]

Comment: Here's the problem is that the length of an array must be a non-negative integer. Use Array.from()

Comment: @Nahid can you explain more where should I update? I am not using specific JavaScript since this is asp.net web project.

Comment: When I hit my submit button, I don't see a progress bar like you do. Does that posted markup REALLY create a working progress bar? I don't see how the posted code makes a progress bar appear? What does the submit button code look like?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I have updated my code above to make clear why please wait is showing.

Comment: `new Array(l/m)` where `m` is either `2` or `1` and `l` is the length of some other array. Image what happens if `l == 5` and `m == 2`. Then you are trying to create a `new Array(2.5)` which is obviously an invalid value for the length of an array

Comment: @derpirscher yes you are correct but I am struggling how do we handle this since i am not using Java script in the code ? I have updated my question and added my debug that i have found through browser debug.

Comment: I have no experience with asp.net, so I don't know where this code is coming from ..

Comment: So, looks like user has an AJAX update panel on the web page. (this allows partial updates of a web page, and generates the ajax code for you). So,  more markup, including the markup with the update panel, and also that of the progress panel that shows when you click on a button. There is also a timer in the above triggers, and if that becomes enabled, then of course the progress template will show over and over - making it appear like it never hides. So, we need  more markup, but the user has adopted AJAX controls on that page by way of using an update panel - that's where js code comes from

Comment: So, an update panel allows what we call partial page post backs, and the AJAX JavaScript for this magic to work is auto-generated by the system for you. As noted, the progress bar area is also automatic displayed, but again, we need more of that markup here. Also, the poster notes that the progress bar area NEVER hides ,and keeps showing ---- did the page ALWAYS do this, or just start doing this due to recent changes? I can't imagine that the page ALWAYS worked this way, so, once agian, BOATLOADS of details are being left out here. But, as noted, we need at least the update panel markup.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I have updated my question with full Markup code from .aspx file that is being used. This page was doing same from beginning and I am working on  to fix it but not able to get to make changes.

Comment: Ok, so we have a master page script manager (lots of JavaScript libraries in that). We have a ScriptManagerProxy on this web page (again, even more JavaScript being added to the current page), we have use of the AjaxToolkit (massive amounts of JavaScript in that library), and then we have a user control reference (again, more potential for even more JavaScript to be added to the page).  And the first line of markup? That is asp.net timer, and THAT ALSO adds JavaScript to the page!!!. So, without question these boatloads and boatloads of additional details you provided changes everything here.

Comment: So, how do we attack such a big elephant? Well, in most cases, one bite at a time. So, since we have massive amounts of JavaScript and a whole bunch of 3rd party libaries? We have a rather large challenge due to large amounts of JavaScript libraries here. I would create a new blank master page. Then start introduction of bits and parts from this page one at a time untill the page fails.  I would add the scriptmanager proxy. Busy day, but we can also take a look at the update panel, and a closer  look at those update panel triggers. And I don't see the progress bar markup either...